How can I fill parts inside of closed curve?
I would like to fill all the areas separated by the dashed lines inside the closed curve using different patterns. I have managed to fill some of the areas but not all.
I want to get something like this:

This is the code that I am using.
\documentclass[a4paper,12 pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,pgfplots.fillbetween, decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,patterns.meta,bending}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}


\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        axis lines=middle,
        grid=major,
        xmin=-1.1,
        xmax=20.1,
        ymin=-1.1,
        ymax=18.1,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        xtick=\empty,
        ytick=\empty,
        scale=1.5];
\addplot[name path = A][smooth cycle, tension=1 , very thick] coordinates { (3,5) (11,6) (8,3) (13,2) (15,9) (13,10) (16,12) (9,14) (1,11) (6,8)};
\draw [name path = B][black, dashed] (13,0)  -- (13, 13.79);
\draw [name path = C][black, dashed] (10.28,0)  -- (10.28, 14.);
\draw [name path = D][black, dashed] (6.01,0)  -- (6.01, 13.75);
\draw [name path = E][black, dashed] (0.9,0)  -- (0.9,10.5);
\draw [name path = F][black, dashed] (2.85,0)  -- (2.85, 5);
\draw [name path = G][black, dashed] (7.9,0)  -- (7.9, 3);
\draw [name path = H][black, dashed] (15.,0)  -- (15., 8);
\draw [name path = I][black, dashed] (16.12,0)  -- (16.12, 11.5);
\fill [pattern={Lines[angle=135, distance=4pt,  line width=1pt]}, intersection segments={of=A and B,   sequence={L2--R2}         }];
 \fill [pattern=north east lines,  intersection segments={of=A and D,      sequence={R2--L2}}];
\fill [pattern=grid,intersection segments={of=A and C,sequence={R2--L2}}];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

This is what I get


Welcome to TeX.SE!

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
xmin=-1.1, xmax=20.1,
ymin=-1.1, ymax=18.1,
xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
];
\draw[dashed, thick] (0.9,0) -- (0.9,10.5);
\draw[dashed, thick] (2.85,0) -- (2.85,5);
\draw[dashed, thick] (6.01,0) -- (6.01,13.7);
\draw[dashed, thick] (7.9,0) -- (7.9,3);
\draw[dashed, thick] (10.28,0) -- (10.28,14);
\draw[dashed, thick] (13,0) -- (13,13.79);
\draw[dashed, thick] (15,0) -- (15,8);
\draw[dashed, thick] (16.12,0) -- (16.12,11.5);
\draw[smooth cycle, tension=1, very thick] plot coordinates {(3,5) (11,6) (8,3) (13,2) (15,9) (13,10) (16,12) (9,14) (1,11) (6,8)};
\clip[smooth cycle, tension=1] plot coordinates {(3,5) (11,6) (8,3) (13,2) (15,9) (13,10) (16,12) (9,14) (1,11) (6,8)};
\fill[pattern=north east lines] (0,8) rectangle (6.01,14);
\fill[pattern=crosshatch] (0,0) rectangle (6.01,8);
\fill[pattern=horizontal lines] (6.01,5) rectangle (10.28,14);
\fill[pattern=grid] (6.01,0) rectangle (10.28,5);
\fill[pattern=vertical lines] (10.28,0) rectangle (13,14);
\fill[pattern=north west lines] (13,0) rectangle (15,10);
\fill[pattern=crosshatch dots] (13,10) rectangle (16.12,14);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thank you so much!
